# .navigationTitle not showing up in Previews or Simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

Building a watchOS app for the first time, and for some reason I'm not able to get the title to show up.

I just made a few initial changes to ContentView:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "drop")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("some info")
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationTitle("title")
    }
}
```

Everything within the VStack is displayed in the preview, but no matter where I put navigationTitle, it doesn't show up in the corner like it should. It doesn't show up either in the previews or simulator. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you could be missing a navigation view but it's hard to tell without seeing if you have the `ContentView` inside a navigation view.

Let's look to the docs for a sec:

[navigationTitle(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationtitle(_:)-5di1u) - "...On iOS and watchOS, when a view is navigated to inside of a navigation view, that view’s title is displayed in the navigation bar..."

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SomeOtherView()
            }
            .navigationTitle("title")
        }
    }
}
```

In my example above, I use `NavigationView`, which you will see widely in SwiftUI project written in the past few years.  However, `NavigationView` has been deprecated and replaced by other navigation types. Take a look at the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack) for `NavigationStack` to see if your watchOS version is compatible with the new navigation types!

Comment: Yup unfortunately it's still the same effect, not showing up in preview but it syntactically works

Comment: Nevermind, NavigationStack seems to work!